# imagemagick skew or distort an image

Tags: php, imagemagick, typo3

Well how could I change the before image to the after image by using imagemagick?
Is it the -skew command or the -distort, and how can I use it preferably in typo3 and php?

Any help is appreciated!

[image: before and after]

Comment: I think you missed to accept an answer. Bonzo's, for example -- I know it is working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Imagemagick with php and the command line:

```
// Working on the original image size of 400 x 300
$cmd = "before.jpg -matte -virtual-pixel transparent".  
" +distort Perspective \"0,0 0,0  400,0 400,22  400,300 400,320  0,300 0,300 \" "; 
exec("convert $cmd perspective.png");
```

Note:
1/ This is for later versions of Imagemagick - the perspective operator has change.
2/ You need to use +distort not -distort as the image is larger than the initial image boundrys.

Examples of Imagemagick with php usage on my site http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/operator.php

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is the [`Imagick::shearImage`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/imagick.shearimage.php) function.  This creates a checkerboard square and distorts it into a parallelogram (save this as a PHP file and open in your browser to see):

```
<?php
$im = new Imagick();
$im->newPseudoImage(300, 300, "pattern:checkerboard");
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->shearImage("transparent", 0, 10);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $im;
?>
```

Within a larger script, to shear an image named *myimg.png* and save it as *myimg-sheared.png*, you can use:

```
$im = new Imagick("myimg.png");
$im->shearImage("transparent", 0, 10);
$im->writeImage("myimg_sheared.png");
```

If `shearImage` isn't versatile enough, you can try the `Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE` method via the [`Imagick::distortImage`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/imagick.distortimage.php) function.

Answer (score 4):

**[Perspective distortion](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective)** should give you what you want. Example:

```
convert original.png -matte -virtual-pixel white +distort Perspective '0,0,0,0 0,100,0,100 100,100,90,110 100,0,90,5' distorted.png
```

In TYPO3 you could apply it by (ab)using the `SCALE` object of the **[GIFBUILDER](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.5.1/view/1/8/)**. Example:

```
temp.example = IMAGE
temp.example {  
  file = GIFBUILDER
  file {
    format = jpg
    quality = 100
    maxWidth = 9999
    maxHeight = 9999
    XY = [10.w],[10.h]

    10 = IMAGE
    10.file = fileadmin/original.png

    20 = SCALE
    20 {
      params = -matte -virtual-pixel white +distort Perspective '0,0,0,0 0,100,0,100 100,100,90,110 100,0,90,5'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the distortion with the imageMagickExec function in Typo3. But there is no effect while others like rotate are working. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Test in the console that IM does what you want by executing the first code that I provided. It should give you pretty much what you want as I tested the code. If not, you will have to check your installation of IM. If yes, test the second TypoScript code I provided. I didn't test that one though.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm battling with IM, still cannot get distort to run while rotate and others are working